# Forcing Unload/Deconstruction of Dynamically Imported File from Source

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

Been a longtime browser of SO, finally asking my own questions!

So, I am writing an automation script/module that looks through a directory recursively for python modules with a specific name. If I find a module with that name, I load it dynamically, pull what I need from it, and then unload it. I noticed though that simply del'ing the module does not remove all references to that module, there is another lingering somewhere and I do not know where it is. I tried taking a peek at the source code, but couldn't make sense of it too well. Here is a sample of what I am seeing, greatly simplified:

I am using Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda v4.2.0). I am using importlib, and that is what I want to stick with. I also want to be able to do this with vanilla python-3.

I got the import from source from the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly%22here%22) (yes I am aware this is the Python 3.6 docs).

My main driver...

```
# main.py
import importlib.util
import sys

def foo():
   spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('a', 'a.py')
   module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
   spec.loader.exec_module(module)
   print(sys.getrefcount(module))
   del module
   del spec

if __name__ == '__main__':
   foo()
   print('THE END')
```

And my sample module...

```
# a.py
print('hello from a')

class A():
   def __del__(self):
      print('SO LONG A!')

inst = A()
```

Output:

```
python main.py
HELLO FROM A!
2
THE END
SO LONG A!
```

I expected to see "SO LONG A!" printed before "THE END". So, where is this other hidden reference to my module? I understand that my del's are gratuitous with the fact that I have it wrapped in a function. I just wanted the deletion and scope to be explicit. How do I get a.py to completely unload? I plan on dynamically loading a ton of modules like a.py, and I do not want to hold on to them any longer than I really have to. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *circular reference* here, the module object references objects that reference the module again.

This means the module is not cleared immediately (as the reference count never goes to 0 by itself). You need to wait for the circle to be broken by the garbage collector.

You can force this by calling [`gc.collect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect):

```
import gc

# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
   foo()
   gc.collect()
   print('THE END')
```

With that in place, the output becomes:

```
$ python main.py
hello from a
2
SO LONG A!
THE END
```

Comment: Ahh, that certainly did it! Accepted your answer. Thank you!